# sum of ceiling function inequality

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to show the following inequality:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{D_j}{Q_j} \left\lceil\frac{Q_j}{T_c}\right\rceil \right) \ge \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n D_j}{\sum_{j=1}^n Q_j} \left\lceil\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n Q_j}{T_c}\right\rceil$$

in which, we know the followings:
$D_j \ge Q_j$,

$D_j$ are all integer, and same as $T_c$, which is a constant term.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thank you for your reply.
No, it is not a home work. It is a research problem I am working on, and the context is on multi-product ordering inventory problem.

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Are all of the $D_j,Q_j$ and the constant $T_c$ positive integers?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality need not hold. Take $n=2,D_1=3,Q_1=2,D_2=4,Q_2=3,T_c=2.$ Then using $c(x)$ for the ceiling of $x$, the inequality in this case would say
$$(3/2)c(2/2)+(4/3)c(3/2) \ge (3+4)/(2+3)c((2+3)/2).$$ 
But the left side is $3/2+(4/3)\cdot 2=25/6=4.1666..,$ while the right side is $(7/5)\cdot 3=21/5=4.20.$

I tested and found lots of cases in the $n=2$ case where the inequality fails. The above was just a small one for which we have each $D_i$ greater than the corresponding $Q_i$.

Comment: @AliBozorgi It may be useful for you to add to this question (or in another question) something about how you came up with the possible inequality. Others may know the general situation and also there may be already known inequalities which may serve your purpose.